# pickle data is deleted when list is appended to after restarting program

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, pickle

Every time I restart my program it displays the previously appended to and pickled lists. The problem occurs when I try to add new data to the list. The previously stored data is deleted and the new data is pickled. I am really confused and have been trying to figure this out for 2 days. Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Background about my program:
I am trying to make a gui that will give me the ability to easily save various types of data so I can later use that data to make visual representations.

Here is my whole program:

```
import pickle
import os
os.system("clear")
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("first gui")
#Program
#Functions
tips = []
days = []
amount_of_cars = []
weather = []
temperature = []



def add_all_stuff():
    pickle1 = open("tips.txt","wb")
    pickle2 = open("days.txt","wb")
    pickle3 = open("cars.txt","wb")
    pickle4 = open("weather.txt","wb")
    pickle5 = open("temperature.txt","wb")
    a1=tips_ask.get()
    a2=days_ask.get()
    a3=cars_ask.get()
    a4=weather_ask.get()
    a5=temperature_ask.get()
    print(temperature_ask.get())
    print(weather_ask.get())
    print(cars_ask.get())
    print(days_ask.get())
    print(tips_ask.get())
    tips.append(a1)
    days.append(a2)
    amount_of_cars.append(a3)
    weather.append(a4)
    temperature.append(a5)
    print(tips)
    print(days)
    print(amount_of_cars)
    print(weather)
    print(temperature)
    #pickle dumps
    pickle.dump(tips, pickle1)
    pickle1.close

    pickle.dump(days, pickle2)
    pickle2.close

    pickle.dump(tips, pickle3)
    pickle3.close

    pickle.dump(tips, pickle4)
    pickle4.close

    pickle.dump(tips, pickle5)
    pickle5.close

def show_lists():
    pickle_in1 = open("tips.txt", "rb")
    tips = pickle.load(pickle_in1)
    print(tips)

#labels
tk.Label(win, text = "menu").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(win, text= "Tips").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(win, text= "Day").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(win, text= "Amount of Cars").grid(row=3)
tk.Label(win, text= "Weather").grid(row=4)
tk.Label(win, text= "Temperature").grid(row=5)
#entryboxes
tips_ask = tk.Entry(win)
tips_ask.grid(row=1, column=1)

days_ask = tk.Entry(win)
days_ask.grid(row=2, column=1)

cars_ask = tk.Entry(win)
cars_ask.grid(row=3, column=1)

weather_ask = tk.Entry(win)
weather_ask.grid(row=4, column=1)

temperature_ask = tk.Entry(win)
temperature_ask.grid(row=5, column=1)
#Buttons
tk.Button(win, text="add", command = add_all_stuff).grid(row=6, column = 1)
tk.Button(win, text="View saved lists", command = show_lists).grid(row=6, column=2)
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the pickle data in first. You're opening the files for writing but not reading the data in before that to the variables you append to. Opening 'wb' overwrites the file. So

```
    pickle1 = open("tips.txt","wb")
```

deletes and opens an empty file for writing.

you can add

```
def add_all_stuff():
    tips = open("tips.txt","rb")
    days = open("days.txt","rb")
    amount_of_cars = open("cars.txt","rb")
    weather = open("weather.txt","rb")
    temperature = open("temperature.txt","rb")
    #... the rest of your code, that should help
```

UPDATE: Here is a full program that works, even after closing:

```
import pickle
import os
os.system("clear")
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("first gui")
#Program
#Functions
tips = []
days = []
amount_of_cars = []
weather = []
temperature = []


def get_make_pickle_data(filename):
   if os.path.isfile(filename):
       pickle_data = pickle.load( open( filename, "rb" ) )
   else:
       pickle_data = []
       pickle.dump( pickle_data, open( filename, "wb" ) )
   return pickle_data


def add_all_stuff():

    tips=get_make_pickle_data('tips.txt')
    days=get_make_pickle_data('days.txt')
    amount_of_cars=get_make_pickle_data('amount_of_cars.txt')
    weather=get_make_pickle_data('weather.txt')
    temperature=get_make_pickle_data('temperature.txt')

    a1=tips_ask.get()
    a2=days_ask.get()
    a3=cars_ask.get()
    a4=weather_ask.get()
    a5=temperature_ask.get()
    print(temperature_ask.get())
    print(weather_ask.get())
    print(cars_ask.get())
    print(days_ask.get())
    print(tips_ask.get())
    tips.append(a1)
    days.append(a2)
    amount_of_cars.append(a3)
    weather.append(a4)
    temperature.append(a5)
    print(tips)
    print(days)
    print(amount_of_cars)
    print(weather)
    print(temperature)
    #pickle dumps


    pickle1 = open("tips.txt","wb")
    pickle2 = open("days.txt","wb")
    pickle3 = open("amount_of_cars.txt","wb")
    pickle4 = open("weather.txt","wb")
    pickle5 = open("temperature.txt","wb")


    pickle.dump(tips, pickle1)
    pickle1.close

    pickle.dump(days, pickle2)
    pickle2.close

    pickle.dump(amount_of_cars, pickle3)
    pickle3.close

    pickle.dump(weather, pickle4)
    pickle4.close

    pickle.dump(temperature, pickle5)
    pickle5.close

def show_lists():
    tips=get_make_pickle_data('tips.txt')
    days=get_make_pickle_data('days.txt')
    amount_of_cars=get_make_pickle_data('amount_of_cars.txt')
    weather=get_make_pickle_data('weather.txt')
    temperature=get_make_pickle_data('temperature.txt')
    print(tips,days,amount_of_cars,weather,temperature)

#labels
tk.Label(win, text = "menu").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(win, text= "Tips").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(win, text= "Day").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(win, text= "Amount of Cars").grid(row=3)
tk.Label(win, text= "Weather").grid(row=4)
tk.Label(win, text= "Temperature").grid(row=5)
#entryboxes
tips_ask = tk.Entry(win)
tips_ask.grid(row=1, column=1)

days_ask = tk.Entry(win)
days_ask.grid(row=2, column=1)

cars_ask = tk.Entry(win)
cars_ask.grid(row=3, column=1)

weather_ask = tk.Entry(win)
weather_ask.grid(row=4, column=1)

temperature_ask = tk.Entry(win)
temperature_ask.grid(row=5, column=1)
#Buttons
tk.Button(win, text="add", command = add_all_stuff).grid(row=6, column = 1)
tk.Button(win, text="View saved lists", command = show_lists).grid(row=6, column=2)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! is there any way you can edit the code and show me where I need to add it? I am relatively new to python and sometimes it just gives me a headache lol.

Comment: I added coded you could add to the beginning, let me know if that helps

Comment: I apologize in advance. I am extremely confused with this pickle stuff. I am getting an error now that I added the code and changed all of the "rb"s to "a"s.

Comment: I removed the "a", i think in your case it's best to read the data and then rewrite the file, so you can keep the "wb", as long as you read with "rb" first. Does that make sense? I can post a complete working copy of the code if you'd like. you really shouldn't open the files for writing until your ready to write as well, so you don't lose data if your program crashes, so i wouldn't open for writing until your done with everything else

Comment: If you could post a complete copy that would be awesome!

Comment: traps, i added code for a working program. Would you be so kind to checkmark and uptick my post if this answer is helpful to you. I can make or modify it more if you'd like, but i think this is a good start

Comment: I really do appreciate this! Its exactly what I was needing!